# How do you change the number registered for iMessage?

Tags: iphone, messages

I want to delete the red one shown in the screenshot.
I can not seem to change it or tap it somehow. Can somebody help?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more information? Do you want to change with a new number that is currently used in your phone?

Comment: Yes. Someones number is there

Comment: 'Someone's?? Some random someone, or did the phone used to belong to someone else? If so, has the phone been completely reset **and** removed from iCloud? If not, then the phone number will be the least of your worries.

Answer (score 1):

### According to Apple, all you need to do is sign out of your device

[image] **Source:** https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage
Check your iCloud preferences after signing out and back in.
*Settings › iCloud › User Account › Contact Information*

### If you are unable to remove/modify

Depending on your carrier, you may need to remove your sim and reinstall iOS.